# Securing Smarty -> any way of getting all assigned variables?

Tags: php, security, smarty

I've created an extra layer where users can use own Smarty code in a sort of HTML template module, but I need to be sure it's save.

So far I've disabled use of `{php}`-tags and only `{$smarty.now}` is accessible. I'm wondering if there is a way, because of the existence of Smarty in the template, to get all assigned variables to the template? If so, how is a list of all assigned variables requested so I can develop a check for that and exclude it from being parsed (means: left out the tpl-source once submitted by the user).

Any help or contributions which I'm overlooking for 'securing'/limiting Smarty-access is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may not suit your needs, but in a similar situation, I used [PHPTAL](http://phptal.org/) as an alternative to Smarty as it is less convoluted and thus easier to control in regards to what goes in and what comes out.  ---

It uses a different paradigm from Smarty to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is a wrong approach to take something way too powerful and limiting it in order to secure it. Famously Java is failing on that many years on their browser plugin. Instead, if you want to have really secure solution I would suggest writing your own tiny templating engine that only will have functionality you need to provide to your users. In that case there will be no way for exploitation for bad guys.

Comment: Which, in the end is the same solution but having another layer on top of it. I don't agree with you on this point. Smarty is fully available for the rest of the site, but in this particular 'area' I want to offer Smarty, but limited.

Comment: I don't suggest building another layer on top of the Smarty. I am suggesting to build something like limited small Smarty from scratch.

Comment: That won't suit me, because I need if-else, foreach and sections. It would be too much of a hassle to built that from scratch. Therefore I'm looking to secure/limit the Smarty possibilities which might reveal other information, like all assigned variables ;) Thanks for your reply and comment though.

Comment: In that case I would suggest using another instance of smarty just for code written by users. You will need another Smarty object the you will fetch result and integrate into your main smarty output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is `$smarty->getTemplateVars();` This will give you an array with the names/values of the assigned template variables.

Quoting from [the API documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl):

> ### Name
>
> getTemplateVars() — returns assigned variable value(s)
>
> ### Description
>
> `array getTemplateVars(string varname);`
>
> If no parameter is given, an array of all assigned variables are returned.
>
> **Example 14.31. getTemplateVars**
>
> ```
> <?php
> // get assigned template var 'foo'
> $myVar = $smarty->getTemplateVars('foo');
>
> // get all assigned template vars
> $all_tpl_vars = $smarty->getTemplateVars();
>
> // take a look at them
> print_r($all_tpl_vars);
> ?>
> ```